# Помогите с инвентарём!

Tags: unity3d

Я сделал инвентарь но проблема в то что предметы могу быть только в слотах а в руки их взять нельзя. Пожалуйста помогите cделать так чтоб предметы можно было взять в руки. Код
Inventory.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Invertory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool [] isFull;
    public GameObject[] slots;
    public GameObject inventory; // сундучёк при нажатии на который выскакивает инвентарь

    private bool InventoryOn;

    private void Start()
    {
        InventoryOn = false;
    }

    public void Chest() 
    {
        if (InventoryOn == false)
        {
            InventoryOn = true;
            inventory.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (InventoryOn == true)
        {
            InventoryOn = false;
            inventory.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

}
```

PickUp.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Invertory invertory;
    public GameObject slottButton; // префаб , иконка в инвентаре

    private void Start()
    {
        invertory = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Invertory>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < invertory.slots.Length; i++) // проходимся по всем слотам
            {
                if (invertory.isFull[i] == false)
                {
                    invertory.isFull[i] = true;
                    Instantiate(slottButton, invertory.slots[i].transform);
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Slot.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Invertory invertory;
    public int i;

    private void Start()
    {
        invertory = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Invertory>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (transform.childCount <= 0)
        {
            invertory.isFull[i] = false;
        }
    }

    public void DropItem()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            child.GetComponent<Spawn>().SpawnDroppedItem();
            GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

Spawn.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject item; // обэкт который находитса на сцене (не иконка)
    private Transform player;

    private void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }

    public void SpawnDroppedItem()
    {
        Vector2 playePos = new Vector2(player.position.x + 0.2f, player.position.y - 0.1f);
        Instantiate(item, playePos, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, удалите опечатки из текста вопроса, расставьте запятые и исправьте заголовок на "безвосклицательный", описывающий суть проблемы

Comment: Ваш код это тихий ужас. Навыка нет. [Учитесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCmenTuz7P8&t=927shttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCmenTuz7P8&t=927s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас есть метод SpawnDroppedItem(), то создайте на его основе другой, например SpawnItemInHand() (можете как угодно назвать),  и добавьте пустышку на сцену и переместите её на координаты, где должен быть предмет и поместите её в объект игрока.

```
public Transform Pustishka;
public Gameobject SelectedObj;

SpawnItemInHand()
{
    Selectedobj = Instantiate(inventory.item[i], Pustishka, Quaternion.identity); 
}
```

Добавьте это в функцию, которая отвечает за выбор предмета, но перед его запуском SpawnItemInHand() сверяй предмет, который хочешь взять и предмет, который у тебя в руках(SelectedObj), если они разные удаляй прошлый и спавнь выбранный.